# Invite friend to a fan page

Tags: javascript, web, facebook-javascript-sdk, invite

I have a webpage with a button for invite friend to a fanpage on facebook, i display the invite friends popup but if i invite a friend he recive a invitation to my app that use for declare de FB js objetc, is posible to invite friends to a facebook page or other url?
My webpage is out of facebook.
Y put my code:

`//CODE JS

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId: 'ID OF MY APP', // App ID from the App Dashboard
            channelUrl: '', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status: true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) { alert('You liked the URL: ' + response); });
    };

    // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
    // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
    // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
    // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
    (function (d, debug) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/ false));
    function ListaAmigos() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Hello'
        }, respuesta);
        //FB.getLoginStatus(onFacebookInitialLoginStatus);
    }`
```

Thank you for any help and sorry for my bad english!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a little trick, this invitations redirect to my facebook app, but with some parameters and if the page recive this parameters i redirect to the fanpage